# Liferay portlet: redirect to an other jsp page from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, liferay, portlet, alloy-ui

I want to redirect to an other jsp page in a liferay portlet from js. The idea that I found is using a renderurl. The best code that I found that can help me as a first step is this one:

```
<a id="renderURLWithJS" href=""> This render URL link is created with Javascript</a>
<aui:script>
    AUI().use('liferay-portlet-url', function(A) {
    var param="Hello new jsp"; 
    var renderUrl1 = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
    renderUrl1.setWindowState("<%=LiferayWindowState.NORMAL.toString() %>");
    renderUrl1.setParameter("param",param);
    renderUrl1.setParameter('mvcPath', 'display.jsp'); /* is this correct???*/
    renderUrl1.setPortletMode("<%=LiferayPortletMode.VIEW %>");
    A.one("#renderURLWithJS").set('href',renderUrl1.toString());
    });
</aui:script>
```

But the problem is that I'm always redirected to the same actual page (view.jsp) not to the jsp page that I want display.jsp.

Does someone have an idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Do your both JSPs reside in same portlet?

Comment: yes it's in the same portlet

Answer (score 1):

Liferay needs to know the target portlet for any request parameter that you add to an URL - otherwise it ignores any unknown parameter. The ID of the target portlet is either defined as `p_p_id` or it is a prefix of the parameter (in which case you can define parameters for more than one portlet in one URL).

So in your case you will have to set `renderUrl1.setPortletId('...your portlet id');` to let your portlet see `mvcPath` and `param`.

In addition the `mvcPath` must be absolute (start with a `/`) and below the configured `templatePath` (defaults to `/`).

Comment: Thank you @Tobias Liefke for the answer. But that didn't correct the problem. I added this line: renderUrl1.setPortletId('objectllclogin_WAR_objectllcloginportlet');
I inspected the link this is what I found as code

Comment: <a id="renderURLWithJS" href="/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=17806&amp;p_p_id=objectllclogin_WAR_objectllcloginportlet&amp;p_p_lifecycle=0&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_state=normal&amp;_objectllclogin_WAR_objectllcloginportlet_param=Hello%20new%20jsp&amp;_objectllclogin_WAR_objectllcloginportlet_mvcPath=display.jsp"> This render URL link is created with Javascript</a>

Comment: Is that the portletID that is rendered by Liferay itself in other URLs? For example If your portlet is instanceable, it will have to include an instanceId as well.

Comment: Yes that's the only Id that I found
The instance id that I get is null

Comment: I make it /display.jsp and I added to portlet.xml that:

  <init-param>
   <name>template-path</name>
   <value>/</value>
  </init-param>

I think that's what you mean
But it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778745/liferay-portlet-basic-mvc-flow-and-view-selection?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your JSP ->

```
<portlet:renderURL var="myRenderURL">
  <portlet:param name="jspName" value="display.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<aui:a href="#" cssClass="myLink" label="Click me" />

<aui:script>
  A.one('.myLink').on('click', function () {
    window.location.href = '${myRenderURL}';
  });
</aui:script>
```

Then in your java portlet class ->

```
@Override
public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) 
    throws IOException, PortletException {

  String jspName = ParamUtil.getString("jspName", "view.jsp");
  include("path/to/your/jsp/" + jspName, request, response);

}
```

One last note: Starting with Liferay 6.2, portlet urls created with javascript methods mentioned in the OP above will

- not include authentication tokens (p_auth, p_p_auth)
- not be converted to friendly urls by the portal.

Also see the [Liferay Documentation](http://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-portlet-urls-in-javascript-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-07-en) on this.