# issue to call a jsp from a SpringMVC Liferay portlet

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, liferay

I have a SpringMVC portlet into a Maven built project.
I can't have a JSP to render to another JSP.

I am not sure if it is because of my JSP path or because of something I misundertood with SpringMVC.

My jsp full path is :
/src/main/webabb/WEB-INF/jsp/render/logs.jsp

I try to call it this way :

```
<aui:button-row cssClass="...">
    <portlet:renderURL var="myURL">
        <portlet:param name="mvcPath"
            value="render/logs.jsp" />
    </portlet:renderURL>

    <aui:button onClick="<%=myURL.toString()%>"
        value="my button" />
</aui:button-row>
```

I tried with

```
value="/webabb/WEB-INF/jsp/render/logs.jsp" />
value="webabb/WEB-INF/jsp/render/logs.jsp" />
value="/WEB-INF/jsp/render/logs.jsp" />
value="WEB-INF/jsp/render/logs.jsp" />
value="/jsp/render/logs.jsp" />
value="jsp/render/logs.jsp" />
value="/jsp/render/logs.jsp" />
value="jsp/render/logs.jsp" />
value="/render/logs.jsp" />
value="render/logs.jsp" />
```

Whatever string, I set, when I hit the button, the page just calls the main controller which redirects to my default view jsp.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Liferay Portlet Basic MVC Flow and View Selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778745/liferay-portlet-basic-mvc-flow-and-view-selection)

Comment: Hi Tobias,
Not really a duplicate of this post you linked.
The post you linked describes a way to get from the controller to a jsp.
In my case, I try to go from a jsp to another jsp.

Comment: I found inportlet-application-context.xml :
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
 </bean>

So we could expect the renderURL to be:
       <portlet:renderURL var="addGuestbookURL">
        <portlet:param name="mvcPath"
            value="render/logs" />
    </portlet:renderURL>

no luck

Comment: You should integrate that information into your query. And onClick is usually a JavaScript function, not an URL

Comment: In order to display another JSP you have to call a renderMethod. Maybe you should read Spring MVC Portlet tutorial (http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently (correct me if I m wrong), we need to call the controller and it will redirect to the JSP.
I managed to have it work this way:

In my JSP:

```
<%-- URL declarations --%>
   <portlet:renderURL var="logsURL">
        <portlet:param name="action"
            value="viewLogs" />
    </portlet:renderURL>
        <portlet:renderURL var="failURL">
        <portlet:param name="action"
            value="fail" />
    </portlet:renderURL>

<%-- buttons--%>
<aui:button-row cssClass="guestbook-buttons">

    <aui:button onClick="<%=logsURL.toString()%>" value="test MVC logs" />
    <aui:button onClick="<%=failURL.toString()%>" value="test MVC fail" />
</aui:button-row>
```

Into my controller:

```
@RenderMapping(params = "action=fail")
    public String fail() {
        LOG.info("\n#############Calling fail###########");
        return "<my_dir>/fail";

    }

@RenderMapping(params = "action=viewLogs")
    public String logs() {
        LOG.info("\n#############Calling logs###########");
        return "<my_dir>/logs";

    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Indeed you have to call a renderMethod. The result if the name of the jsp you want to display (defined by <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">)